# Combinatorics : # of ways to invite the guests

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

At the moment we are doing combinatorics and probability at school and it is a branch of mathematics that interests me probably more than anything else.

Upon doing some of my own research I´ve come across a combinatorics problem from some past math contest and I am trying to find an efficient way to solve it.

The problem is quite simple:
A person hosts a dinner for his friends every evening for 7 days straight. He has 7 friends in total and everyday, 3 of them are invited. How many ways can the host invite his 7 friend such that every one of them participates at least once?

Now the last condition just breaks everything. Without it it would be easy, but also not interesting at all.

No formula seems to do the trick here and considering all the options is out of the question as well..

We know that he invites 3 out of his 7 friends, which translates to: 
$$\ {7 \choose 3}^7 = \left({7!\over 3!(7-3)!}\right)^7$$
From that we would now need to subtract the options where the same guests are invited, which is again ridiculously inefficient.

The one thing that occurred to me, was to try and think about it in a way such that when one of the guests wasn´t invited, it is as if the host only had 6 friends. If two weren´t invited, it is as if he only had 5 friends and so on.
Which should translate to having some sets $A_1$ - $A_7$ such that the $i$-th friend is never in the set $A_i$ and, if I am not mistaken, the result should be:
 $$\ {7 \choose 3}^7 - {7 \choose 1}{6 \choose 3}^7 + {7 \choose 2}{5 \choose 3}^7 - {7 \choose 3}{4 \choose 3}^7 + {7 \choose 4}{3 \choose 3}^7
$$

Can you see something wrong with the thought process or the actual formula?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you started adding every term. Inclusion/exclusion would say to add/subtract alternately, right? And why isn't the first term raised to the 7th power?

Comment: How many days of invitations are here?  Is your exponent $7$ supposed to suggest that there are seven dinners?

Comment: It is.. There are seven days. I edited the first post, thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is a typo, but the first term in the expression should be to the seventh power, and the second to last should be negative.

Comment: After those edits, I think you have the right answer; it's just a matter of inclusion, exclusion, where the ambient set is the set of all possible guest lists for that week, properties $a_i$ denoting when a list of guests excludes guest $i$ for $i=1,2..7$, and you want $e(\emptyset)$ or the set of all lists with none of those properties. With more than 4 properties, the terms become 0, because there's no way to invite 3 people with only 2 friends, so you have the answer. Good job!

Comment: Yes, this is fine